# Why isn't my revised .NET Windows Form not showing new changes after running the program again?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, design-time

In my desktop application, previously I have designed the form and ten execute it but then I went for slight changes in my form.But even after changing, while I run the program now the previously created form is getting displayed.

What might be the problem...could anyone help me?

Comment: Are the changes being compiled? That could be the problem.

Comment: Please post some code so that we can atleast know what are you doing

Comment: yes the previously designed form is compiled and then I made changes

Comment: I mean, did you compile after making the changes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

Delete all the \BIN directories in your solution

Build->Clean project

Rebuild All

Answer (score 1):

Another place to check is the solution build configuration.

Make sure your project is being built. 
If it is not being built, then your changes wont show up.

1. Right click solution.
2. Configuration Manager.
3. Verify your project is selected.

Answer (score 0):

When you make changes to, say, *Form1*, in the visual designer, Visual Studio will reflect those in the code found in the file called *Form1.Designer.cs*, in the method called *InitializeComponent()*. That's one place you can check for errors.